# Daily Reputation Cap

Tags: support, reputation

Was there a recent change to the daily reputation cap, setting one at 230, or is that a sudden bug?

Either way the Help Center is out of date, still reporting a cap of 200 (was there any before the split?).

https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation

Comment: Accepted answers don't count towards the cap. Nor do bounties.

Comment: @Deduplicator Looking at your reputation yesterday, you had quite a bit of rep gained in accepted answers. That's where it came from.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cap is still 200, however the 15-point reward given for having your answer Accepted is exempt from this cap - so you can exceed the cap by posting answers that are accepted by the askers.

#### See: [What's Reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Needed some more of the linked exemptions to explain things, but that explained it. Should have searched on the meta-meta-site.

Comment: What happens with the +100 association bonus? Is it also exempt?

Comment: It is, @Matsmath. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation